# Linker command failed with error code 1 in tipsi-twitter

Tags: ios, react-native

I am making a react native app which uses a package named `npm i tipsi-twitter`
The app works fine in android build but while making ios build it gives me error that

```
"_TWTRScribeEventImpressionTypeLoad", referenced from:
      +[TWTRScribeSink tweetLoadNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventImpressionTypeShare", referenced from:
      -[TWTRScribeSink didShareTweetWithID:forUserID:fromViewName:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink tweetViewShareNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventUniquesAction", referenced from:
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitTweetViewUsageNamespaceWithTweetViewStyle:showingActions:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitLoginUsageNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventUniquesClient", referenced from:
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitTweetViewUsageNamespaceWithTweetViewStyle:showingActions:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitLoginUsageNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink timelineUniqueNamespaceWithTimelineType:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
      +[TWTRScribeSink verifyCredentialsUniqueNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventUniquesPageLogin", referenced from:
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitLoginUsageNamespace] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventUniquesPageTweetViews", referenced from:
      +[TWTRScribeSink twitterKitTweetViewUsageNamespaceWithTweetViewStyle:showingActions:] in TwitterKit(TWTRScribeSink.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have linked that package in my project.Kindly help me with this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding JavaScriptCore.framework in link binary with Libraries solves this issue